# Android AprilBeacon

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I am trying to develop an app using `Beacons`. I have bought an `AprilBeacon 241` device. However i couldn find any good tutorial for that. Is there any experienced bluetooth developer that can guide me with some tutorials/examples on how to connect to `AprilBeacon` and manipulate with it?
The `sdk library` is located in [Github](https://github.com/AprilBrother/AprilBeacon-Android-SDK/blob/master/README.md)  but i was not able to understand the documenation they provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this library if your are developing with android

[alt beacon](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html)

and use this layout

[Android layout parser of AprilBeacons Altbeacon library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872555/android-layout-parser-of-aprilbeacons-altbeacon-library)