# Android layout parser of AprilBeacons Altbeacon library

Tags: android, parsing, layout, ibeacon

I want to know what is the parser of AprilBeacons .
Already i searched information about this but they all use the SDK libraries, we are using Altbeacons libraries because we use Estimote and April Beacons.

This parser is for Estimote

> mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

We need the layout for April Beacons.

The the support´s answer was:

*The advertising data of AprilBeacon have 31 bytes not 30 bytes. It can be parsed by iOS iBeacon api. The length of manufacture data is 0x1B not 0x1A. You can print the raw data to found the difference.*

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The parser of AprilBeacons it´s same:

> mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new
>   BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));